# Can I add SSH key to my GitLabCI machine?

Tags: ios, swift, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently I run gitlab-runner with my MacOS machine for be CI to my iOS project
but stuck with this error.

[image]

I think it about SSH can someone help me to fix this?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-known_hosts-entries), add the following to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (under the user account that gitlab-runner also uses):

```
gitlab.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIAfuCHKVTjquxvt6CM6tdG4SLp1Btn/nOeHHE5UOzRdf
gitlab.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsj2bNKTBSpIYDEGk9KxsGh3mySTRgMtXL583qmBpzeQ+jqCMRgBqB98u3z++J1sKlXHWfM9dyhSevkMwSbhoR8XIq/U0tCNyokEi/ueaBMCvbcTHhO7FcwzY92WK4Yt0aGROY5qX2UKSeOvuP4D6TPqKF1onrSzH9bx9XUf2lEdWT/ia1NEKjunUqu1xOB/StKDHMoX4/OKyIzuS0q/T1zOATthvasJFoPrAjkohTyaDUz2LN5JoH839hViyEG82yB+MjcFV5MU3N1l1QL3cVUCh93xSaua1N85qivl+siMkPGbO5xR/En4iEY6K2XPASUEMaieWVNTRCtJ4S8H+9
gitlab.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFSMqzJeV9rUzU4kWitGjeR4
```

Comment: How to add ? T_T sorry I'm new to it.

Comment: On your MacOS machine, log in with the user gitlab-runner is also using, then in your home directory, create a directory `.ssh`. Inside this directory, create a file called `known_hosts` (no extension) containing the contents above.

Comment: for gitlab runner, After I registerd and run it. How to access or login to it ? TT

Comment: FYI, For my local machine I already add ssh and known host but not yet on gitlab-runner

Comment: So gitlab-runner isn't running on your local machine? Where is it running then? If you have registered and run it, you already must have had access to it, don't you?